Snowflake data flattening
I have an array of JSON
'[
    {"key": "cId", "value": "d03ce656"},
    {"key": "cName", "value": "Healthcare"},
    {"key": "pId", "value": "d869628b"},
    {"key": "pName", "value": "ConveYour"}
]

I want to convert it to
{
  "cId": "d03ce656",
  "cName": "Healthcare",
  "pId" : "d869628b",
  "pName": "ConveYour"
}

so far I have tried
SELECT
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
        parse_json(f.value):key::string, 
        parse_json(f.value):value::string
    ) AS json_object
FROM LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON('[
    {"key": "cId", "value": "d03ce656"},
    {"key": "cName", "value": "Healthcare"},
    {"key": "pId", "value": "d869628b"},
    {"key": "pName", "value": "ConveYour"}
]')) AS f;

but it gives me
JSON_OBJECT
{    "cId": "d03ce656"  }
{    "cName": "Healthcare"  }
{    "pId": "d869628b"  }
{    "pName": "ConveYour"  }

I do not want 4 rows but one element {
"cId": "d03ce656",
"cName": "Healthcare",
"pId" : "d869628b",
"pName": "ConveYour"
}

You need to use the aggregate function OBJECT_AGG() :
SELECT OBJECT_AGG(
        parse_json(f.value):key, 
        parse_json(f.value):value
    ) AS json_object
FROM LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON('[
    {"key": "cId", "value": "d03ce656"},
    {"key": "cName", "value": "Healthcare"},
    {"key": "pId", "value": "d869628b"},
    {"key": "pName", "value": "ConveYour"}
]')) AS f
GROUP BY f.this;

Results :
JSON_OBJECT
{   "cId": "d03ce656",   "cName": "Healthcare",   "pId": "d869628b",   "pName": "ConveYour" }

